# La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un problema con registro y actualizaciones en mi BD, estoy utilizando Laravel con SqlServer me sale el siguiente error

Al parecer es mi bd porque levante un el mismo preyecto en una version anterior que tengo en mi git y me sale el mismo error.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: te esta diciendo que no puedes convertir un nvarchar en datetime por que el tipo de valor datetime no es compatible en la conversion y excede el intervalo, esto sucede pro que tienes datos en la tabla. lo que puedes hacer si no estas aun en produccion es:

Comment: hacer un backup solo de la data, vaciar la tabla, convertir la columna de tipos... volcar nuevamente la data.